# Custom authorization filter always returning 404 when I'm trying to force a 401

Tags: asp.net, attributes, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to write my own authorization attribute where I run through some custom checks on any web api method with the CustomAuthorization attribute.

My code is as follows:

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            //// Attempt 1 - 404 error.  
            //// Doesnt block method with this attribute from executing (not desired behaviour).

            //context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            //return; 

            //// Attempt 2 - 404 result. 
            //// Code with attribute doesnt execute (desired).
            //// Error thrown says:  An exception of type 'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException' occurred in <namespace> but was not handled in user code
            //// Additional information: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

            //throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));

            // Attempt 3 - 404 result. 
            // Code with attribute doesnt execute (desired).
            context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting a 404 response from the web api instead of an expected 401.  What am I doing wrong?

This is asp.net core 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be because you have authentication setup to redirect to a login page for 401 responses and that login page is not being found (happened to me).

Comment: Had the same thing... had cookie auth and header auth set up in the same project, and the cookie auth took precedence, trying to redirect to the login page (which didn't exist if it was an API-only project). Splitting them and only using the header auth solved it.